# ExoPlayer2 - How can I make a HTTP 301 redirect work?

Tags: android, http, redirect, exoplayer, exoplayer2.x

I started using ExoPlayer to stream some audio. All was well until I came across an URL that has a "301 Moved Permanently" redirect. ExoPlayer2 does not handle that by default.

I've already seen this thread: https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/issues/423

There they say to add the new "allowCrossDomainRedirects" flag to either a HttpDataSource or UriDataSource. The problem is that I don't use either of those classes:

```
//I am NOT using SimpleExoPlayer because I need a different renderer.
exoPlayer = ExoPlayerFactory.newInstance(renderers, trackSelector, loadControl);

final DataSource.Factory dataSourceFactory = new DefaultDataSourceFactory(
            context,
            Util.getUserAgent(context, applicationInfo.getAppName())
);

// Produces Extractor instances for parsing the media data.
final ExtractorsFactory extractorsFactory = new DefaultExtractorsFactory();

// This is the MediaSource representing the media to be played.
MediaSource mediaSource = new ExtractorMediaSource(
            Uri.parse(media.getUriString()) /* uri */,
            dataSourceFactory,
            extractorsFactory,
            10,
            null /* eventHandler */,
            null /* eventListener */);

exoPlayer.prepare(mediaSource);
```

See how the ExtractorMediaSource requires a dataSourceFactory instead of a DataSource. In fact I can't even find the classes HttpDataSource and UriDataSource on ExoPlayer2. Looks like they have been removed.

Therefore I can't find a way to add the flag mentioned on the post. Can somebody help me?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

The problem described in the issue is about cross-protocol redirects (from http to https or vice versa). Exoplayer supports this, but you have to set `allowCrossProtocolRedirects` to `true`. Regular redirects (including 301 redirects) are supported by default. The redirect you're receiving is most likely a cross-protocol redirect.

To create the data source you're calling:

```
DefaultDataSourceFactory(Context context, String userAgent)
```

This constructor creates a `DefaultHttpDataSourceFactory` which has `allowCrossProtocolRedirects` set to `false`.

To change this, you need to call:

```
DefaultDataSourceFactory(Context context, TransferListener<? super DataSource> listener,
  DataSource.Factory baseDataSourceFactory)
```

And use your own `DefaultHttpDataSourceFactory` with `allowCrossProtocolRedirects` set to `true` as the `baseDataSourceFactory`.

For example:

```
String userAgent = Util.getUserAgent(context, applicationInfo.getAppName());

// Default parameters, except allowCrossProtocolRedirects is true
DefaultHttpDataSourceFactory httpDataSourceFactory = new DefaultHttpDataSourceFactory(
    userAgent,
    null /* listener */,
    DefaultHttpDataSource.DEFAULT_CONNECT_TIMEOUT_MILLIS,
    DefaultHttpDataSource.DEFAULT_READ_TIMEOUT_MILLIS,
    true /* allowCrossProtocolRedirects */
);

DefaultDataSourceFactory dataSourceFactory = new DefaultDataSourceFactory(
    context,
    null /* listener */,
    httpDataSourceFactory
);
```

If you need to do this more often you can also create a helper method:

```
public static DefaultDataSourceFactory createDataSourceFactory(Context context,
        String userAgent, TransferListener<? super DataSource> listener) {
    // Default parameters, except allowCrossProtocolRedirects is true
    DefaultHttpDataSourceFactory httpDataSourceFactory = new DefaultHttpDataSourceFactory(
        userAgent,
        listener,
        DefaultHttpDataSource.DEFAULT_CONNECT_TIMEOUT_MILLIS,
        DefaultHttpDataSource.DEFAULT_READ_TIMEOUT_MILLIS,
        true /* allowCrossProtocolRedirects */
    );

    DefaultDataSourceFactory dataSourceFactory = new DefaultDataSourceFactory(
        context,
        listener,
        httpDataSourceFactory
    );

    return dataSourceFactory;
}
```

This will allow cross-protocol redirects.

Sidenote: "301 Moved Permanently" means clients need to update their URL to the new one. "302 Found" is used for regular redirects. If possible, update the URLs that return "301 Moved Permanently".

Comment: Thanks for the sample code and the explanation - very much appreciated!

Comment: `true /* allowCrossProtocolRedirects */` saved life - Thumbs up :)

Comment: DefaultHttpDataSourceFactory  is not importing , showing error , Please suggest what can i do to resolve it

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
// Build a HttpDataSource.Factory with cross-protocol redirects enabled.
HttpDataSource.Factory httpDataSourceFactory =
    new DefaultHttpDataSource.Factory().setAllowCrossProtocolRedirects(true);

// Wrap the HttpDataSource.Factory in a DefaultDataSource.Factory, which adds in
// support for requesting data from other sources (e.g., files, resources, etc).
DefaultDataSource.Factory dataSourceFactory =
    new DefaultDataSource.Factory(context, httpDataSourceFactory);

// Inject the DefaultDataSourceFactory when creating the player.
ExoPlayer player =
    new ExoPlayer.Builder(context)
        .setMediaSourceFactory(new DefaultMediaSourceFactory(dataSourceFactory))
        .build();
```

It works for me.

Comment: DefaultHttpDataSourceFactory not found in version 2.17.1. How to solve this problem ?

Comment: Sadly this does not work for HLS streams, when they are redirected. But if I use HlsMediaSource instead of DefaultMediaSourceFactory, it works somehow. But HlsMediaSource is not a good solution because other streaming types like MPEG TS won't work anymore.

Answer (score 0):

it works

```
val httpDataSourceFactory = DefaultHttpDataSourceFactory(Util.getUserAgent(context, "Player"),null,DefaultHttpDataSource.DEFAULT_CONNECT_TIMEOUT_MILLIS,
        DefaultHttpDataSource.DEFAULT_READ_TIMEOUT_MILLIS,
        true)

val dataSourceFactory: DataSource.Factory = DefaultDataSourceFactory(context, null, httpDataSourceFactory)
```

Comment: DefaultHttpDataSourceFactory not found in version 2.17.1. How to solve this problem ?

Comment: @denizbaş I'am not familiar with 2.17.1 yet, if your project suitable for downgrading exoplayer, use implementation ('com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer:2.14.+').

Comment: DefaultHttpDataSourceFactory is not importing , showing error , Please suggest what can i do to resolve it

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer looks a little bit outdated , because DefaultHttpDataSource class is deprecated and we suppose to replace it with DefaultHttpDataSource.Factory , [see the official documentation](https://exoplayer.dev/doc/reference/com/google/android/exoplayer2/upstream/DefaultHttpDataSource.html).

So instead of

```
DefaultHttpDataSourceFactory httpDataSourceFactory = new DefaultHttpDataSourceFactory(
    userAgent,
    null /* listener */,
    DefaultHttpDataSource.DEFAULT_CONNECT_TIMEOUT_MILLIS,
    DefaultHttpDataSource.DEFAULT_READ_TIMEOUT_MILLIS,
    true /* allowCrossProtocolRedirects */
);
```

we could have

```
    final DefaultHttpDataSource.Factory defaultDataSourceFactory = new DefaultHttpDataSource
    .Factory()
    .setUserAgent(userAgent)
    .setTransferListener(listener)     
.setConnectTimeoutMs(DefaultHttpDataSource.DEFAULT_CONNECT_TIMEOUT_MILLIS)
    .setReadTimeoutMs(DefaultHttpDataSource.DEFAULT_READ_TIMEOUT_MILLIS)
    .setAllowCrossProtocolRedirects(true);
```

Also don't forget to use if you have to

```
final DefaultHttpDataSource defaultDataSource = defaultDataSourceFactory.createDataSource();
```

And finally guess what : DefaultDataSourceFactory is also deprecated and we should use DefaultDataSource.Factory instead.

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to assign the right *android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"* in the application section of the manifest.
My code to initialize ExoPlayer with http support looks like this:

```
String userAgent = Util.getUserAgent(this, "my app name for example");

HttpDataSource.Factory httpDataSourceFactory =
            new DefaultHttpDataSource.Factory().setAllowCrossProtocolRedirects(true);

player = new ExoPlayer.Builder(this)
            .setMediaSourceFactory(
                    new DefaultMediaSourceFactory(this)
                            .setDataSourceFactory(httpDataSourceFactory))
            .build();
```